# How get text from TRichView of another application?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a handle of TRichView window. How can i get text from it?

I've tried WM_GETTEXT, but without effect, just empty string.

I've also tried EM_SETSEL and WM_COPY, but also without effect.

I really need to get text from this TRichView. Any other methods?

Comment: There is no `TRichView` in WinApi or C++, please be specific, for example Delphi or C++ Builder...

Comment: It's a native vcl control. Likely not possible for you to extract text. UI automation your best hope. Don't be optimistic.

Comment: The VCL's native component is `TRichEdit`, which wraps the standard Win32 `RICHEDIT` control. [`TRichView`](http://www.trichview.com/features/trichview.html) is a 3rd party custom control.

Comment: @Remy TRichEdit is a windows control. TRichView is a pure VCL control. That's what I was trying to say.